# Signing RPM on SLES builds

Tags: jenkins, rpm, sles

I have been trying to enable signing my SLES build RPMs and I get this error:

```
04:30:12 + xargs rpm --resign
04:30:12 error: You must set "%_gpg_name" in your macro file
04:30:12 Pass phrase check failed
04:30:13 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I checked on RH6/7 slave machines, I have sign-rpm installed. on SLES slaves there is no such rpm. I do not simply want to copy over those rpms as I am not sure if they'd work for SLES. Anybody knows which rpm to use for SLES specific signing needs?

Comment: Have you set `_gpg_name` in your RPM macros file? Because that's what the error is saying is the problem. (I have no idea what `sign-rpm` is. Can you run `rpm -qi sign-rpm` on one of the machines that has it?)

Comment: @ Etan The .rpmmacros file doesn't exist on my VM. Should I create one? Also this is SLES, is it the same? Ran rpm -qi sign-rpm on the vm that has it and it says package not installed so sign-rpm has nothing to do with this looks like. ( Earlier I said sign-rpm installed, I should have said the sign-rpm rpm shows under  rpm --last -qa | tac).

Comment: Is `rpm --last -qa | tac` shows a `sign-rpm` package installed them `rpm -qi sign-rpm` should give you information about it. If it doesn't something is wrong. I have no idea what that package is doing. It might be providing the signing configuration for your environment so you don't have to do it manually (and that's why you are hitting this problem). But without finding out what it is I can't say. Do the working VMs have `.rpmmacros` files?

Answer (score 2):

You need pointers to a tutorial on the topic.  The most useful one I have found is Thomas Chung's page *[How to sign your custom RPM package with GPG Key](http://fedoranews.org/tchung/gpg/)*.

The particular step which you had not done is #6 in that page, quoted here:

> 6) Final step before the signing, configure your `~/.rpmmacros` file to include the following:
>
> `%_signature gpg`
>   `%_gpg_name  Thomas Chung`

But of course, you would use your own name for the `_gpg_name` field.